# What's the skinny on the User Profile page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Visiting [our User Profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) using the Firefox Android browser, and the newest site update: rev 2020.2.3.35945, with the browser's menu **Request Desktop Site** unchecked results in **two different widths** for the webpages elements; causing an incorrectly sized webpage and some elements overlapping and unreadable:

[image: Smushed User Profile]

Everything was OK a few hours ago.

Comment: I bet this is an attempt at making those pages responsive, which would be something I very much welcome! Although it could do with a few tweaks.

Comment: `disable responsiveness` is a possible temporary solution.

Comment: @Luuklag It's about time. I always use the full site on my phone and the profile page can get a bit of a hassle.

Comment: I normally have "Request Desktop Site" checked but on one of my tabs it wasn't, when I visited my Profile the evil was revealed. Simply checking the box fixes everything, but it's not correct to be required to do so; and it was OK earlier today. Probably missing a CSS inheritance somewhere ... No panic. Also affects Chrome 79.0.3945.136 for Android.

Comment: It also happens on Chrome 79.0.3945.73, Safari and Firefox on IOS. Must be something that they are doing to the website.

Comment: I noticed this earlier too. But I just checked again now and it seems to be back to normal.

Comment: @AdamLear hi! Is this an indication that there’ll be a responsive profile in the actually near future (i.e. was this part of an attempt to make this page work as a responsive page), or was this just a mistake?

Comment: @Stormblessed This was a side-effect of an unrelated change, but reworking user profiles and making them responsive is something we'd like to do eventually as we work on moving away from having mobile-browser-specific views.