# Tiny communities list block on the Edit Profile Page

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, design, responsive-design

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current

Has something been changed recently? On the communities page the whole block was narrowed.

> [image]

Cause of this css rule:

```
.wmx5 {
    max-width: 40.5128205rem !important;
}
```

Previously it fitted the whole width.

> [image: o]

Was it intentional? Other pages still fits the whole width, so it looks like a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: Part of moving to responsive design.

Comment: This is [INABIAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undocumented_feature) and improves the look; while the [previous occurence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343217/282094) drastically hurt readability and usability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was intentionally narrowed. The amount of scanning the eye has to do back and forth horizontally on each row was not ideal. It was making the page's intended use, hiding and showing communities, harder than it needed to be. There’s a sweet spot where folks can more easily [read the words](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/ideal-column-width-for-paragraphs-online).

Comment: Then you have to narrow the line under the title also.

Comment: Are you having trouble reading the line under the title?

Comment: I have trouble with an inconsistent design. If you narrow the content, you have to narrow the whole block. Right now it looks ugly.